# How can I efficiently read paths stored in a column of a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, image, apache-spark, pyspark

The input to my process is a structured dataset where one column is a GCS path to a blob, something like:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("gs://my/bucket/image.jpg",), ("gs://my/bucket/image2.jpg",)], 
    ["image_path"]
)
```

I want to read the (binary) data from the URIs in that column, and store that data in a new column. Something like:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("image_blob", magic_read_function(F.col("image_path")))
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? I basically want to tell spark to batch the reads as much as possible, but without shuffling or collecting to a single worker... if possible.

Some options I have considered are:

- I could get the list of paths with `paths = [row.image_path for row in df.collect()]` and then read in the list. This will force a shuffle, and gather all paths onto a single worker though, which I'd like to avoid.
- I could make a UDF that reads from the path, but then I get network overhead for each path being read, rather than batching the files to each worker.
- I could read all of the files from the parent bucket, and do an inner join on the URI column(`image_path` in this example). Then I still have to do a shuffle for the inner join though, and I have to assume all input paths are coming from the same bucket (this is typically the case for this process, but there's nothing currently guaranteeing it. I'd like to avoid adding this restriction to the process if possible)

Comment: are your images in the same directory? if so, you could try something like `df = spark.read.format("image").option("dropInvalid", True).load("gs://my/bucket/")`

Comment: Hey Derek O, they typically are but I'd like to avoid assuming they will be. That said, I didn't realize there was a built-in "image" format, and I didn't know about "dropInvalid" so this may be a good option if there's no way around requiring paths from the same bucket!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I'm just using mapPartitions from the rdd API, and batching reads manually with the GCS python client. Here's what I came up with:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
from google.cloud import storage
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import itertools

            
def _get_bucket(row):
    return urlparse(row.image_path).netloc

def _get_path_beneath_bucket(row):
    return urlparse(row.image_path).path.strip("/")
            
def process_partition(rows):
    client = storage.Client()
    
    # group by bucket, so we can efficiently read one bucket at a time
    bucket_blobs = itertools.groupby(rows, key=_get_bucket)
    
    for bucket_name, rows in bucket_blobs:
        bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        # eval iterator, since we'll need it twice
        rows = list(rows)
        
        with client.batch():
            blobs = [bucket.blob(_get_path_beneath_bucket(row)) for row in rows]
            for blob in blobs:
                blob.reload()
        
        for row, blob in zip(rows, blobs):
            yield Row(image_path=row.image_path, image_blob=blob.download_as_bytes())
```

Then I use the function like this:

```py
rdd = df.rdd.mapPartitions(process_partition)
result_df = rdd.toDF()
```

This isn't ideal, partially because I have to leave the tungsten runtime to access the rdd api (which I'm guessing will end up with some performance cost) and partially because it's sort of messy.

If you know of a better method, I'm happy to accept a different solution to this. :)